# MS Access and MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, permissions, odbc, access-rights

I'm tyring to connect my MS Access frontend to an MSSQL database, this is a big database with many tables and many views. It is prohibited to connect as a sysadmin user.

The SQL's admin has created a user and given rights to this user (even take ownership for a specific table). But MSAccess is incapable to correctly link the tables.

In MS SQL Management Studio I can correctly see the views and tables in the software with this user but when I connect via ODBC connector in MS access while I do see the tables during the linking phase it runs into an error, and does not link the tables correctly.

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxWMh.jpg)

I created a local MS SQL database, and with sysadmin I could easily link the tables, when I switched to a different permission set tough I ran into the same issue.

Does anyone has ran into issues like this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question (edit)! E.g. avoid images show text of error msg (for copy&paste). Software versions (Office, SQL Server, ODBC Driver)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that the user did not have view definition permissions. That's why it did not work.